# global_max value in Kadane's algorithms

Tags: python

I read Kadane;s Algorithms in [Maximum subarray problem - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

I could understand the basic implementation

```
def max_subarray2(A):
    max_current = max_global = A[0]
    for x in A[1:]:
        max_current = max(x, max_current + x)
    if max_current> max_global:
        max_global = max_current 
    return max_global
```

The data declared `max_current = max_global = A[0]`
As for the version to retrieve the starting and ending indices

```
def max_subarray3(A):
    max_current = A[0]
    startOld = start = end = max_global = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(A[1:], 1):
        max_current = max(x, max_current + x)
        max_global = max(max_global, max_current)
        if max_current < 0:
            start = i + 1
        elif max_current == max_global: #when max_global not change
            startOld = start
            end = i
    return (max_global , startOld, end)
```

Now `max_global = 0` rather than `max_global = A[0]`, I don't know why. If all numbers are negative, it will return (0, 0, 1)

Comment: If all numbers are negative, no numbers are greater than zero, thus `max_global` is never updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in whether you consider an empty array as a subarray of every possible A or not.

In such case, the maximum value of sum for an array with only negative values can be considered 0, for the implicit empty array. If you wish to exclude that possibility, you would need to change `max_global = 0` accordingly. That's why the 0 is there.

The article you linked states as much [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm):

> The algorithm can also be easily modified to keep track of the
>   starting and ending indices of the maximum subarray as well as the
>   case where we want to allow zero-length subarrays (with implicit sum
>   0) if all elements are negative.